# detecting native client on end user's laptop from a web page?

Tags: google-nativeclient

Can I detect whether a native client is installed on end user's laptop from a web page using Javascript ?

What approaches can i take to do this ? Are there any Chrome APIs available for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect PNaCl support from JavaScript using `navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-pnacl'] !== undefined`, and swap in `x-nacl` for NaCl.